# SQL Server Bulk Import ROWTERMINATOR vbCrLf (\n) not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know there are other threads on here regarding this problem and none of the recommended fixes are working.  I have verified that the CRLF at the end of each record is a hex '0D0A'.  I can do a replace in VBS on vbCrLf and it replaces every one of them.

Here is a sample of my tab-delimited text file:

```
01/16/2013  11:00   HS01    DocLast, DocFirst PA-C  Occurred    ML  11/20/2012  15:31       
01/07/2013  09:40   HS01    DocLast, DocFirst PA-C  Canceled    ML  11/20/2012  15:36   Patient Canceled    20130103-57935
```

I am executing this code against the text file in a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008:

```
set @sqlcmd = '
BULK INSERT #temp_import_records
FROM ''' + @import_file + '''
WITH
(
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
)'
```

I am trying to insert this text into a temp table with 20 columns. This data only has 10 fields.  With my code, both of these records are being installed into the same record in the temp table. I have tried setting the rowterminator to '0D0A' and '0x0A' and neither of them worked.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would suggest to load this into a temporary table with exactly 10 fields, then select from this table into the final table, #temp_import_records.

Comment: The problem with that is that I'm importing multiple files into this temp table and not all of them have 10 fields.  I'm using a select query to take the contents of this temp table and importing the data, combined with other data, into a permanent table.  Bulk insert doesn't allow me to mix other data with the data being imported so I have to use this two-step process.

Comment: +1. Very nicely asked question.

Comment: What is the encoding of this TSV file? If this is ANSI encoding, you may need to specify CODEPAGE='ACP' in your BULK INSERT command.

Comment: @DavidR, the encoding, when I open the file in Notepad++, is UTF-8 without BOM.  I don't know if it makes a difference - maybe interfering, but my process is that a VB script reads certain file attributes (size, number of lines) then executes the SQL stored procedure.

Comment: Does any pre-processing or file IO occur prior to the bulk insert?

Comment: @DavidR, I have also tried converting the import file to ANSI and to UTF-8 and only import the file (without the VBS piece) with no success, so no.

Comment: I still haven't been able to get this to work so I'm taking a different approach.  I'm using a temp table with a fixed number of fields based on the data type being imported.  It makes for a longer conditional import script but it works every time.  Oh well.  Thanks for everyone's ideas.  I've always found this site to be useful but this is the first time I've ever posted anything.

Answer (score 6):

For anybody landing here now, you can try using HEX codes

`ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0d0a'` or `ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'`

Comment: You are my hero mate

Comment: yes, the real MVP

Comment: But in my case my development machine is windows and application deployed in linux. How i can set the ROWTERMINATOR as per the platform.

Answer (score 0):

The `\n` character is only the `LF` (0A) part of the two character `CR+LF` (0D0A) row terminator. Use `\r` for the first part:

```
 ROWTERMINATOR = ''\r\n''
```

Comment: I have tried that as well.  When I do that, I get two records imported into a single record in the temp table.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest also escaping the termination like so:

```
ROWTERMINATOR = ''\\n''
```